# Enumerable.Range.Aggregate Method deal with long integer type

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to solve the [Project Euler problem 20.](http://projecteuler.net/problem=20)

```
n! means n × (n − 1) × ... × 3 × 2 × 1

For example, 10! = 10 × 9 × ... × 3 × 2 × 1 = 3628800,
and the sum of the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27.

Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!
```

My code is returning a wrong result because it can't deal with long integer type.

```
        BigInteger x = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Aggregate((total, next) => total * next);
        int[] y = Array.ConvertAll(x.ToString().ToArray(), a => (int)a);
        Console.WriteLine(y.Sum());
```

As at some step the variable

> total

became very big then it was not int type.

I wrote an extension for Range but had difficult time for Aggregate method. My whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace p20
{
    class Program
    {
        // Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DigitsSum();
        }

        private static void DigitsSum()
        {
            BigInteger x = ExtentionLong.Range(1, 100).Aggregate((total, next) => total * next);
            int[] y = Array.ConvertAll(x.ToString().ToArray(), a => (int)a);
            Console.WriteLine(y.Sum());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
    public static class ExtentionLong
    {
        public static IEnumerable<long> Range(this long source, long length)
        {
            for (long i = source; i < length; i++)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes required

- `Select(i=>new BigInteger(i))`
- `a => (int)(a-'0')`

---

```
BigInteger x = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i=>new BigInteger(i)).Aggregate((total, next) => total * next);
int[] y = Array.ConvertAll(x.ToString().ToArray(), a => (int)(a-'0'));
Console.WriteLine(y.Sum());
```

BTW: You can simply do this

```
var sum   = x.ToString().Sum(d => d - '0');
```